# Save data after Twitter Oauth

Tags: twitter

I have a textbox on my site where people can enter a tweet
when submitting if the user is not already logged in he will be redirected to twitter's page to login
however after this the original tweet that the user typed is lost. is there a way to keep this info?

is it true that with oauth I must redirect the user to twitter's login page? i can't have a popup? or put it in an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

i would do it with `$_SESSION` if you are using php?